# Method not returning same result as a block of code in main. Identical code

Tags: c#, methods, marshalling, intptr

I am making a console application that sends and returns data in c# to a dll(c++), and returns it.
I made it work but run into a problem I cant understand.

When I call a block of code in the main method it works, but when I make a method (with the same block of code) and call it from the main method, it breaks. I don't know how to explain better so I'll put the code for you to see.

```
 [DllImport("ActivatorDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
 public static extern IntPtr fullname(byte[] firstname, byte[] lastname);

 static void Main(string[] args) 
 {
     string fn = "Foo";
     string ln = "United";

     IntPtr nameResult  = fullname(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(fn), Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ln));

     
     int len = 0;
     while (Marshal.ReadByte(nameResult, len) != 0) ++len;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
     Marshal.Copy(nameResult, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     string res = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);

     string res2 = StringFromNative(nameResult);

     Console.WriteLine(res);
     Console.WriteLine(res2);

     Console.ReadLine();
 }

 public static string StringFromNative(IntPtr native)
 {
     int len = 0;
     while (Marshal.ReadByte(native, len) != 0) ++len;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
     Marshal.Copy(native, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     return Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
 }
```

res is working as intended. res2 however is not working

[image: result]

Thanks!

I tried looking for a solution or explanation on here and on other platforms but couldn't get an answer anywhere.

the fullname function from the cpp of the dll

```
char* fullname(char* firstname, char* lastname)
{
    char result[1000] = ""; 
    strcpy_s(result, firstname);
    strcat_s(result, " ");
    strcat_s(result, lastname);
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think you miss a "DllImport" in your static Function. Try to put "DllImport" in above static Function.

Comment: Without knowing the implementation in the C++ dll it is hard to know for sure, but my guess is that the result has been de-allocated. In fact, it is probably a small wonder that the first call succeeds. How is the memory allocated?

Comment: What `fullname` function does? Its code is missing.

Comment: Indeed, your C++ code is wrong. It is allocating `result` on the stack, which is then dumped. Instead you should pass in a buffer from C# which is then filled. Furthermore, you don't need to manually marshal it in bytes, just pass `string` or `StringBuilder` between them. Why do you need this C++ function anyway?

Comment: @Charlieface I'm preparing something because we need a c# smaller program to comunicate with a c++ bigger program. It needs to be like this. Now I need to find out how to pass a buffer from c# to the dll. Any tips greatly appreciated :) Thanks to you and everyone else for answers!

Comment: So you want a C++ function like `int fullname(const char* firstname, const char* lastname, char* buffer, int bufferSize)` which returns how many bytes have been set, then you define it in C# as `.... CharSet.Ansi)] public static extern int fullname(string firstname, string lastname, StringBuilder buffer, int bufferSize);` and create a `StringBuilder` buffer of sufficient size and pass it in.

Comment: @Charlieface ok, looks promising :) I'm trying it rn but i see you changed the cpp function from char* to int. What would I return in this case? how would the cpp function look like? Thanks again!

Comment: Like I said, you return the total number of characters inserted into the buffer, so you know where to truncate it when you get it back.

Comment: @Charlieface But my goal is to put in "firstname" and "lastname" and get back "firstname lastname". I'm a beginner as you can probably see. Could you (or anyone else) show what you would do in the c++ function in this case?

Comment: So when you call that function, you do `var myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(1000); var numBytesWritten = fullname(myfirstname, mylastname, myStringBuilder, myStringBuilder.Capacity); var result = myStringBuilder.ToString(0, numBytesWritten);`

Comment: @Charlieface Some stuff I understand quicky, but this is making me insane lol. How do I get the size of the buffer in the c++ dll file function? If I do it like you said up here I just get back the same buffersize of 1000 (the one I put in)...

Comment: Well what are you returning from C++? You need to change that code to return the correct length.

Comment: int fullname(const char* firstname, const char* lastname, char* buffer, int bufferSize)
{
 char result[1000] = ""; 
 strcpy_s(result, firstname);
 strcat_s(result, " ");
 strcat_s(result, lastname);

 buffer = result;

 bufferSize = strlen(result);
 
 return bufferSize;
}

Thats what i have so far. But not working correctly....

Comment: No that's wrong. You want something like `{ strcpy_s(buffer, firstname); strcat_s(buffer, " "); strcat_s(buffer, lastname); bufferSize = strlen(buffer); return bufferSize; }` note that it's probably better to just kepp track of how many bytes you are adding rather than using `strcat` and calculating it every time.

Comment: @Charlieface I get the no instance of overloaded strcpy_s matches arguments error...but how can i 'construct' the "firstname lastname" string without it? And how can I keep track of how many bytes I'm adding? And thanks again for all the help

Comment: `strcpy_s(buffer, buffersize, firstname);` maybe? I don't know C++ well enough. You can use `strlen` to work out the size of what you are copying, then simply add it up.